# Fusion Vectors in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, orientation, line

In **Matlab** I've got two matrices,L1 and L2, containing in each row the coordinates (row, column) of several points in 2D space:

```
L1=[1,1;2,2;3,3];
L2=[4,4;5,5;6,5;7,6;8,7];
```

After plotting I've got this:

[image: Red line is L1 and blue one represents L2]

I'm trying to implement an algorithm that could **fusion** lines that are **similarly orientated**. I've tried for quite a while. I guess that the simplest way of solving this is to follow these steps:

-First: suppose that L1 and L2 are two segments of the same line(L3).

-Next: Starting from (1,1) (or (8,7)) evaluate the orientation of the next point. In other       words, the orientation that point (2,2) has from (1,1), point (3,3,) from (2,2), etc. And save those values.

-Next: Calculate from all orientation values the average value.

-Next: evaluate if the fusion points between fibers, that in this case are (3,3) and (4,4), follow a similar orientation.

-Results: If previous stage is TRUE, then fusion the fibers. If FALSE, do nothing.

One key point here is to establish a reference from which orientation angles can be measured. Maybe this approach is too complicated. I guess there is a simpler way and less memory consuming way. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code -

```
% We need to set a tolerance value for the similarity of slopes between the
% main data and the "fusion" data. This tolerance is in degrees, so basically
% means that the fiber must be within TOL degrees left or right of the overall data average.
TOL = 10;

% Slightly different and a more general data probably
L1=[2,3;3,5;4,10];
L2=[7,15;8,19;9,21];
L_fiber = [L1(end,:);L2(1,:)];

% Slopes calculation
a1 = diff(L1);
m1 = a1(:,2)./a1(:,1);

a2 = diff(L2);
m2 = a2(:,2)./a2(:,1);

% Overall slope for the main data
m = mean([m1;m2]);

a_fiber = diff(L_fiber);
m_fiber = a_fiber(:,2)./a_fiber(:,1);
m_fiber_mean = mean(m_fiber);

% Checking if the fiber mean is within the limits set by TOL
deg_max = atan(m)*(180/pi) + TOL;
deg_min = atan(m)*(180/pi) - TOL;

slope_max = tan(deg_max*pi/180);
slope_min = tan(deg_min*pi/180);

if m_fiber_mean >= slope_min && m_fiber_mean <= slope_max
    out = true;
    disp('Yes the fusion matches the overall data');
else
    out = false;
    disp('No the fusion does not match the overall data');
end
```

Hope this settles it!

Comment: Wow! Really impressive! I was thinking how about using the slopes of the lines but I didn't know how to do it. Thank you for such a quick response. Now I'm trying your code with more complex lines, let see how it works...

Comment: Edited for a better usage of the tolerance for similarity.

Comment: So TOL are now degrees?

Comment: Yes, as documented in the code. Sorry about the changes, it was needed for a more easy to understand code and usage.

Comment: oh! yes, I didn't read it. Thank you! I was really frustrated with this.

Comment: Divakar, I think there should be an additional restriction when adding/subtraction the TOL value. For example, imagine that angles "deg_max" and "deg_min" are above -90 degrees. If the TOL value is high enough to turn, for example, deg_min below -90 degrees then, when calculating "slope_min" I will have a value very different from that I have when deg_min is just a degree over -90. In other words, if the limit of 90º is passed, when calling to "tan" function (due to the discontinuity of this function) two similar orientated fibers are not joined. How can I solve this? Thank you

Comment: I guess that by adding (some how) the tolerance value after computing the "tan" could solve this.